# How to ignore auto-capitalization for specific words but keep it intact normally in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a brand name (similar to iPhone, in that it's camal-case with a lower-case first letter) that I always want to keep lower-case, even when it's at the beginning of a sentence.

I'm using Microsoft Word 2013.

For example:

`iPhone is a phone by Apple.`

instead of

`IPhone is a phone by Apple.`

I also want to keep auto-correcting bad lower-case letters at the beginning of sentences. I only want to ignore the lower-case brand name. Because of this, I can't simply disable "Capitalize first letter of sentences" in AutoCorrect options.

**How do I configure Microsoft Word 2013 so that I can auto-capitalize most words except my specific brand names?**

Comment: Interesting.  I have Word 2013, I just installed it recently and haven’t done much to configure it (in fact, I’ve made a point of _not_ tweaking anything global; I only occasionally change a style locally to a document), and yet I can’t reproduce your problem.  I got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XGbk8.png), typing everything in lower case except for “tHe”, “iPhone”, “Apple”, and “iXylophone”.  Is there any chance that you made a configuration change that brought about this undesired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that you **specify exceptions to automatic capitalization**. In order to do this, you'll have to open a list in Microsoft Word that contains words that contains specific formatting for the casing of each letter in said word.

---

## Specify exceptions to automatic capitalization in Word 2013

Start by opening Microsoft Word 2013, and clicking `File` in the ribbon toolbar.

[image: File]

Now click `Options`

[image: Options]

Now click `Proofing`

[image: Proofing]

Now click `AutoCorrect Options...`

[image: Autocorrect Options]

Now click `Exceptions...` (Ensure that the "Correct TWo INitial CAps checkbox is checked!)

[image: Exceptions]

Now click `INitial CAps`

[image: INitial CAps]

Now type the word in that with the exact casing you'd like to use under the "Don't correct:" field.

Now click `Add`

[image: Enter word]

Click `OK`, and try it out!

[image: OK]

[image: it works!]

If you'd like to read up more on how to do this, you can see the [Office Support Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Automatically-correct-capitalization-88319b2b-4199-49e6-82d5-1138110e1714).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to add it to the known wordlist by right-clicking it?

Comment: We are looking for answers with content more than a single sentence. Please elaborate on why this answers the question and include applicable sources as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Shift with space ( not only space) after the word and it will keep in small letter without capitalizing the first letter, so you can keep it automatically for the other sentences and do it only for the word you want to keep the first letter small.

I hope it answered your Q.